# After open up LabVIEW, always need to reload DLL for VI to do LoadLibrary function

Tags: c, dll, labview

Currently, I have encountered an issue within LabVIEW.
Every time after I open the LabVIEW program, I was trying to do the function VI which would does I2C initialization by execute LoadLibrary function to load the I2C DLL.
Then it always cannot find the I2C DLL, which is next to the function VI.

However, after I reload the DLL to this function VI, then it works. The process is I open the VI and then select the DLL again.

I don't know if any of you have met the similar issue? Does anyone has nice solution?

Comment: how do you specify the DLL path? relative or absolute? What do you mean exactly by saying "reloading the DLL to this function VI"?

Comment: When LabVIEW cannot find the DLL, what is the exact error message?

Comment: Hello, all, Thanks for your reply! The issue is sometimes I used hDll = LoadLibrary(_TEXT("name.dll")); and hDll returns Null. So it couldn't find it. But if I use Visual Studio run it. Then it has no problem. The name.dll is beside the executable.

Comment: Labview doesn't return any error. Because it's calling the function from DLL library. So DLL library would call the function which using LoadLibrary function to load another i2c communication DLL. And after I just created the VI, it works fine to load the i2c communication DLL. But after I closed the Labview then open it again, it cannot find this dll, which also means it loads NULL to hDll

Comment: Just to be sure. You do save the VI.